# How to get/update all user profiles via CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, user-profile, user-profile-service, app-permissions

I need to get and update user profile properties in SharePoint Online via CSOM using App only permissions. I am using .NET core CSOM.

App is registered via `appinv.aspx` page.

Permissions:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" /> 
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Here is a sample code:

```
ctx =  new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(config.TenantURL, "id", "secret");
PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(userName);
// PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();
ctx.Load(personProperties);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

If I try to get my personal profile it works fine (`GetMyproperties`). But it fails if I try to get anyone else's profile.

Could someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will need **Full Control** permissions to access the User Profile properties of other users.

**Sample code**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;

namespace UserProfilesCSOM
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Replace the following placeholder values with the target SharePoint site and
            // target user.
            const string serverUrl = "http://serverName/";  
            const string targetUser = "domainName\\\\userName";  

            // Connect to the client context.
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);

            // Get the PeopleManager object and then get the target user's properties.
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(targetUser);

            // Load the request and run it on the server.
            // This example requests only the AccountName and UserProfileProperties
            // properties of the personProperties object.
            clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var property in personProperties.UserProfileProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", 
                    property.Key.ToString(), property.Value.ToString()));
            }
            Console.ReadKey(false);

            // TODO: Add error handling and input validation.
        }
    }
}
```

**Source**: [Retrieve user profile properties by using the .NET client object model in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-net-client-object-model-in)

**Additional References**:

1. [Retrieve User Profile Properties From SharePoint Using CSOM PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-user-profile-properties-from-sharepoint-using-csom/)

Comment: I can read docs myself, thanks! :D
As I said I am using full control permissions already
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />